# `str_detect()` and `map()` to iterate through many string detections

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, tidytext

My data is in the format below. (Code for data input at the very end, below question).

```
#> df
#>  id amount description
#>   1     10 electricity
#>   2    100        rent
#>   3      4        fees
```

I would like to be able to classify the transactions (rows), based on whether certain strings are in the description.

So for example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(category = ifelse(str_detect(description, "elec"), "bills", description))
```

which gives:

```
#>   id amount description category
#> 1  1     10 electricity    bills
#> 2  2    100        rent         
#> 3  3      4        fees
```

I'd like to be able to define a vector of keywords and the associated categories, as below:

```
keywords <- c(electric = "bills",
              rent = "bills",
              fees = "misc")
```

What is the next step to be able to create the categories column with the correct labels?

Desired Output:

```
#>   id amount description category
#> 1  1     10 electricity    bills
#> 2  2    100        rent    bills         
#> 3  3      4        fees    misc
```

I've tried `map2_df`, but I must be doing something wrong, because the code below creates three versions of the df stacked on top of each other:

```
categorise_transactions <- function(keyword, category){df <- df %>% 
  mutate(category = ifelse(str_detect(description, keyword), category, description))}

library(purrr)
map2_df(names(keywords), keywords, categorise_transactions)
```

code for data input below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
            amount = c(10L, 100L, 4L),
       description = c("electricity", "rent", "fees")
)
df
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, it sounds like you may need ```case_when```?  If you do a search for ```[case_when]``` and ```[r]``` you should find  a lot of useful examples on how to use.

Comment: based on @RussThomas's very helpful comment above, I found this previous question that should be helpful for anyone looking at this question in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886082/is-there-a-way-to-use-for-loops-within-dplyr-to-reduce-the-number-of-str-detect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_replace_all` almost gives what you need :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(df$description, keywords)
#[1] "billsity" "bills"    "misc"
```

However, as suggested by @Russ Thomas `case_when` gives exactly what you need.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(str_detect(description, 'electric') ~ 'bills', 
                              str_detect(description, 'rent') ~ 'bills', 
                              str_detect(description, 'fees') ~ 'misc'))  


#  id amount description category
#1  1     10 electricity    bills
#2  2    100        rent    bills
#3  3      4        fees     misc
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the `keywords` vector into the `case_when()`? Or would you recommend using the syntax you provided above? Thank you, it's such a helpful answer.

Comment: It would not be any shorter, you could do `str_detect(description, names(keywords)[1]) ~ keywords[1]` and so on for others. Regarding your attempt, with `map2_df` in every iteration you get the entire dataframe back hence, the result dataframe has 3 times more rows than original. It will work if you use `for` loop.